# Degree of the polynomial $f(x)=0$

Tags: polynomials, soft-question

If $f(x)=c$ then degree of $f(x)$ is $0$. **(c $\neq 0$)**

If $f(x)=Ax+B$ then degree of $f(x)$ is $1$. **(A $\neq 0$)**

If $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ then degree of $f(x)$ is $2$. **(A $\neq 0$)**

Now in this manner we can identify the degree of any polynomial.

But my question is if $f(x)=0$ , it means that $x^0$ has zero as its coefficient.

That is there are no $x^0$ terms in $f(x)$ .

Then what is its degree ?

Comment: Sometimes it is convenient to define the degree of the zero polynomial to be $-\infty$, and sometimes it is simply left undefined.

Comment: We like for $deg(f\cdot g) = deg(f)+deg(g)$.  What choice for degree for the zero function satisfies that?

Comment: @JMoravitz Can you explain it more ? Thank you

Comment: Why an earth can't it simply be 0?  The degree of a polynomial is the largest x^n value that varies and has significant.  If $n \ge 1$ and a_n = 0 then $0 x^n$ can not be  significant so the degree must not be n.  That is the only reason that we point out that $a_n \ne 0$.  That isn't relevant for constant polynomials as no $x^n$ vary so none are significant.  So power is 0 and the restriction that $a_0 \ne 0$ is not only not nescessary but is inappropriate.

Comment: As an aside, in case anyone might come up with the thought that we can fix the issue by simply not calling the zero function a polynomial, that would be terribly inconvenient as we like to talk about the polynomials (*or polynomials up to a certain degree*) as a vector space and so must include zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the degree of a non-zero polynomial, the following relations hold:
\begin{aligned}
\deg (-f) &= \deg f\\
\deg (f+g) & \le \max \{\deg f,\deg g\}\\
\deg (fg) &= \deg f+ \deg g
\end{aligned}
Now we want this to hold also for the degree of the zero polynomial.

Now for any polynomial, $f+(-f) = f-f=0$. Therefore according to the relations above, for any polynomial $f$:
$$\deg(0) = \deg(f+(-f)) \le \max \{\deg f,\deg (-f)\} = \deg f$$

The smallest degree of a non-zero polynomial is $0$ for a constant polynomial. Therefore we get
$$\deg(0) \le 0$$
On the other hand, for any polynomial, $0f=0$, therefore according to the third relation, we get for every $f$:
$$\deg 0 = \deg(0f) = \deg 0 + \deg f$$
That equation is obviously not fulfilled by *any* integer. Indeed, not even by any real number. Therefore one possible decision is to just leave the degree of the zero polynomial undefined, as there's no number that has the required properties.

However, if you look a bit beyond the integers, there are some "numbers" that indeed fulfil that inequality: $\pm\infty$. If you add anything finite to one of them, then the result is still $\pm\infty$. Now the other requirement is that $\deg(0)\le 0$, therefore the one selection that works is $-\infty$. Therefore it is common to define
$$\deg(0) = -\infty$$

Now you may be worried that computing with $-\infty$ might cause all sorts of problems. But it turns out that this is not the case, as all you ever do with it is add it either to itself, or to a natural number. Basically $-\infty$ does for addition what $0$ does for multiplication of positive numbers: It's smaller than all of them, and it forces the result to itself: If any term is $-\infty$, then so is the sum, and if any factor is $0$, so is the product. Indeed, this connection can be made more rigorous by noting that you can map addition to multiplication through the exponential function:
$$\exp(x+y) = \exp(x)\exp(y)$$
The obvious definition for $\exp(-\infty)$ is
$$\exp(-\infty) = \lim_{x\to-\infty}\exp(x) = 0$$
and then you get
$$0 = \exp(-\infty) = \exp(-infty + x) = \exp(-\infty)\exp(x) = 0\exp(x) = 0$$
so indeed everything is consistent.

And indeed, it is not really surprising that this "additive zero" $-\infty$ appears in the degree, because like the exponential function, the degree function maps multiplication (of polynomials) to addition (of integers). Therefore the zero polynomial (which obviously acts as a $0$ under multiplication) is mapped to the "additive zero" $-\infty$.

Comment: We call this property of always mapping to itself, that $-\infty$ is *absorbing* under addition.  In this regard it's the additive analogue of multiplying by zero. Furthermore this operation is *idempotent* since subsequent repetitions of the first addition of $-\infty$ are *nullipotent* - they leave the result of the original operation unchanged. These properties arise out of the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under addition, and $-\infty$ represents the subtraction of a sufficiently large number to transcend that closed boundary.