# Degree of the homogenous function $f(x)=0$

Tags: functions

A homogenous function is a function such that, when its arguments are multiplied by a scalar, the value of the function is multiplied by some constant power of that scalar, e.g:
$$f(kx) = k^nf(x), \text{ where } k \in \mathbb{R}$$

Sometimes $k > 0$, but in most cases, I think this is all that is required for a function to be homogenous.

The constant $n$ is referred to as the degree of the homogenous function.

Is the function: $f(x) = 0$, a homogenous function? Since it seems like one:

$$f(kx) = 0 \text{ and } k^nf(x) = 0$$

If so, what degree is this? $log(0)$? $-\infty$? undefined?

I'm guessing it's similar to the [polynomial version of this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879739/degree-of-the-polynomial-fx-0), but I have no good reasoning or argument for this, other than they both have similar looking degrees.

Perhaps I've misunderstood homogenous functions?

Comment: Degree of $0$ is not defined.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy For polynomials or homogenous functions? If it is for homogenous functions, is there a source for this?

Comment: $f(x)$ is homogeneous function of degree $n$, when $f(kx)=k^n f(x)$ for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$, except $k< 0$ for fractional $n$ and $k=0$ for $n\leq 0$. The $n$, not $k$ is referred to as the degree of the homogeneous function $f(x)$. Most functions are non-homogeneous or homogeneous with definite degree, but $f(x)=0$ is homogeneous function of any degree.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Ah yep, whoops, missed that. Will fix that now. It does feel a bit strange that a function can have multiple degrees? I guess it's possible with piecewise, but are there other homogenous functions that have be multiple degrees?

Answer (score 0):

In hopes of closing this, here are some reasons why degree of the homogenous function $f(x) = 0$ could be any degree.

If you check $f(x) = 0$ against the requirements for:

$$\text{Degree 0: } f(kx) = f(x)$$
$$\text{Degree 1: } f(kx) = kf(x)$$
$$\text{Degree 2: } f(kx) = k^2f(x)$$
$$\ldots$$

It is quite clear that $f(x) = 0$ satisfies the requirements for any degrees.

We can also manipulate a homogenous function and directly obtain $n$:
$$f(kx) = k^nf(x)$$
$$\frac{f(kx)}{f(x)} = k^n$$
$$\log_k\left(\frac{f(kx)}{f(x)}\right) = n$$
$$\text{Let } k = e, \text{ then } \ln\left(\frac{f(ex)}{f(x)}\right) = n$$

This works for some common homogenous functions such as:
$$g(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 \implies \text{Choose } x = 1,\ \ln\left(\frac{g(e, e)}{g(1, 1)}\right) = \ln\left(e^2\right) = 2$$
$$h(x, y) = \frac{y}{x} \implies \text{Choose } x = 1,\ \ln\left(\frac{h(e, e)}{h(1, 1)}\right) = \ln\left(1\right) = 0$$

However, this doesn't work for our function: $f(x) = 0$, since it tries to divide by zero. Perhaps it has more than one degree?

Neither of these prove the degree of the homogenous function $f(x) = 0$ but provide some intuition. While this doesn't seem like a consensus, [most](https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/which-of-the-following-functions-are-homogeneous-class-12-maths-cbse-60106f1c03e4507026fb22e0) [sources](https://math.unm.edu/%7Eblair/math511s18/hw4_511_s18.pdf) [I came across](https://files.vipulnaik.com/math-195/limitsinmultivarcalc.pdf) say $f(x) = 0$ is of any degree, so perhaps it is.